# Como retornar o resultado de uma função para um arquivo em python

Tags: python, funções

poderiam me ajudar? queria retornar o resultado desta função em um arquivo para depois que gerá-lo o enviar para outra aplicação. já tentei de várias maneiras, porém até abre o arquivo, mas quando olho dentro dele está em branco.

```
    def inventario():
       print('\n*** Ajuste de Inventário ***\n')
       codprod = input('Código do Produto?: ')
       qt = input('Quantidade Contada: ')
       motivo = input('Motivo do Ajuste: ')
       user = input('Solicitante: ')
       return (codprod, qt, motivo, user)
       resultado = open('resultado.txt', 'r+')
       arq = (codprod, qt, motivo, user)
       for x in arq:
             resultado.write(x)
             resultado.write("\n")
             resultado.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código precisa de vários ajustes, vejamos:
A função `inventario()` termina no `return (codprod, qt, motivo, user)`, então as linhas de código após o `return` precisam ser no início da linha, pois da forma que estava identado, tudo pertenceria a função.

```
def inventario():
    print('\n*** Ajuste de Inventário ***\n')
    codprod = input('Código do Produto?: ')
    qt = input('Quantidade Contada: ')
    motivo = input('Motivo do Ajuste: ')
    user = input('Solicitante: ')
    return (codprod, qt, motivo, user)
```

A aplicação fica da seguinte forma, note que está iniciando no começo da linha:

```
resultado = open('resultado.txt', 'r+')
arq = inventario()
for x in arq:
    resultado.write(x)
    resultado.write("\n")
```

`resultado.close()` precisa iniciar no começo da linha também para só fechar o arquivo após o `loop for`.

```
resultado.close()
```

**O código completo fica assim:**

```
def inventario():
    print('\n*** Ajuste de Inventário ***\n')
    codprod = input('Código do Produto?: ')
    qt = input('Quantidade Contada: ')
    motivo = input('Motivo do Ajuste: ')
    user = input('Solicitante: ')
    return (codprod, qt, motivo, user)

resultado = open('resultado.txt', 'r+')
arq = inventario()
for x in arq:
    resultado.write(x)
    resultado.write("\n")

resultado.close()
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Sou novo na linguagem e to aprendendo, mas me ajudou bastante!

Comment: Tranquilo @kurtz_lima, que bom que ajudei. Por favor, visto que é novo por aqui, peço que  confira [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta).